# How do you use a for loop variable as an index for a loop? (JS)

Tags: javascript, for-loop, indexing

I am trying to make it so that when I run the function it checks if there is a save already. If there isn't, then it puts those values in the list. I am using nested arrays and there will be three total saves. But for some reason when I run it, it says that allSaves[L] is undefined. But when I put a zero in for the L, it works. But I can't do that. So does anyone know how I could fix that? Here is my code -

```
    function savingList(principal, interestRate, time, compoundNumber) {
       var allSaves = new Array();
      allSaves[0] = new Array();
      
      for(var L = 0; L < 2; L++) {
        if(allSaves[L].length == 0){
          allSaves[L] = new Array(principal, interestRate, time, compoundNumber);
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: I guess the problem happens when your loop hits L=1.

Comment: oh wow. I forgot to put break. I feel stupid now but its fine. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest creating `allSaves` directly as an `Array.map()` instead of using a traditional loop block. Also note that your iterator variable `L` should be a `let` instead of a `var` so that it is scoped appropriately.

```
function savingList(principal, interestRate, time, compoundNumber) {
  return [...new Array(3)].map(saveIteration =>
    [principal, interestRate, time, compoundNumber]
  )
```

The phrase `[...new Array(i)]` is just a way of getting a map-able array of length `i`.